# How to internationalize an iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, ios, internationalization, ibtool

I am trying to internationalize an iPhone app that was written few years ago and at that time unfortunately internalization was not the priority. As there are lot of nib files I have used ibtool to programmatically generate the nib files for each country. After running the ibtool utility i had to open up the project.pbxproj file and had to insert manual entries for the spanish language. Since i have to update lot of entries i did not choose this route.

I wanted to know how can i generate region specific nib file and have the entries reflected in the project.pbxproj file.

Secondly, I was unable to use gestrings option as the code doesn't use the NSLocalized method every where the text the is hard coded. while i prefer this option is there a safe mechanism to find out all the strings in the code base that can be internationalized?

Apologies for the long question. Any recommendations on how should i go about internationalizing the app?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem recently and came across the following links [iphone-applications-localization-guide](http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/03/15/ibtool-localization-made-easy/) and [ibtool-localization](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/) and [Merging-changes-into-a-localized-nib-file](http://www.scribd.com/doc/62541695/202/Figure10-1-Merging-changes-into-a-localized-nib-file)

maybe it will help you.